# Remove item from menu focus mode learndash Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

El modo de enfoque ofrece dos enlaces de forma predeterminada: 1- la página del curso y 2. Cerrar sesión: ambos no se pueden eliminar del menú de wordpress, ¿cómo puedo eliminar el enlace inicio del curso? ¿Se puede  agregar un fragmento para ocultar este enlace ?. Traté de hacerlo a través de css html pero no obtuve resultados.

Cuando modifico el estilo en el cuadro de inspección del navegador, logro eliminar el enlace:

```html
 <a href="https://expande.org/programa/curso-de-prueba/" style="
    display: none;
">Inicio del Curso</a>
```

Traté de agregar un fragmento de la siguiente de manera para eliminar el enlace:

```html
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', function () {

    $out = '<a href="https://expande.org/cursos/curso-de-prueba/" style="
    display: none;
">Inicio del Curso</a>';

    return $out;
} );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Please, add your code in spanish

Comment: No olvides traducir también tu título :)